# Formulário Ajax e PHP abrir lista dinâmica com consulta SQL

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Amigos, boa tarde!

Preciso editar um formulário que já estava pronto, incluindo algumas opções novas. Não conheço quase nada de PHP, e estou com muita dificuldade de fazer com que a combobox do formulário retorne uma consulta do SQL.

Esse formulário foi desenvolvido com PHP, AJAX e SQL.

Existem 3 arquivos para que os dados apareçam na página web.

**-classificador_HelpCenter.php
-classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php
-classificador_HelpCenter_sql.php**

Esse formulário usa Bootstrap (O que também não entendo muito, infelizmente)

O formulário já tinha configurado, os campos (Usuário, Solicitante e Nome Solicitante), o campo que estou tentando incluir é "Atendimento".

Vou inserir o código dos arquivos AJAX e SQL, para que possam entender melhor e talvez consigam me ajudar.

**-classificador_HelpCenter.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?PHP 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    define( "RAIZ_augusta", "//57.228.131.75/" );
    require_once("//57.228.131.75/icc/funciones/funciones.php" );
    require_once("../../complemento/complemento.php");
    $ua = getBrowser();
    if (strpos($ua['name'],'Internet') === false){
        include_once("../../complemento/analyticstracking.php");
    }
    session_start();


    if(@array_key_exists("34", $_SESSION[ "modulos" ])){ 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Augusta | Classificador Help Center</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE'/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>

    <!-- CSS -->
        <!-- bootStrap -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <!-- jQuery --> 
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>    
        <!-- bootStrap -->
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/html5.js'></script>
        <link href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/bootstrap-ie7.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/icc_ie8.css'/>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/ie.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/IE8.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/ie6.css'/>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            carregar_form(); 
        });
    </script>
    <script> <!-- carregar form -->
        function carregar_form() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarForm'   
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#form_classificador").html("<div class='row text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'><img src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/miniload.gif' alt='Carregando'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#form_classificador").html( data ); 
                        document.getElementById('filtro_Solicitante').value = "";
                    }
                })
            }           
        }
    </script>
    <script> <!-- carrega Atendimento -->
        function carregarAtendimento() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarAtendimento'    
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#form_classificador").html("<div class='row text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'><img src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/miniload.gif' alt='Carregando'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#form_classificador").html( data ); 
                        document.getElementById('filtro_Atendimento').value = "";
                    }
                })
            }           
        }
    </script>
    <script> <!-- carrega subSolicitante -->
        function carregarSubSolicitante() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarSubSolicitante',
                        'Solicitante'   : $('#filtro_Solicitante').val()
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#div_subSolicitante").html("<div class='row text-center' style=''><img style='height:36px;' src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/loadbar.gif'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#div_subSolicitante").html( data ); 
                        document.getElementById('filtro_SubSolicitante').value = "";
                    }
                })
            }           
        }
    </script>
    <script> <!-- function guardar e limpar -->
        function guardar(){
            if (  $( "#filtro_Atendimento" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o Canal de Atendimento");
                $("#filtro_Atendimento").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (  $( "#filtro_Solicitante" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o Solicitante da ligação");
                $("#filtro_Solicitante").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (  $( "#filtro_SubSolicitante" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o nome do Solicitante da ligação");
                $("#filtro_SubSolicitante").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(true) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion'   : 'guardar',
                        'Atendimento'       : $( "#filtro_Atendimento").val(),
                        'Solicitante'       : $( "#filtro_Solicitante" ).val(),
                        'subSolicitante'    : $( "#filtro_SubSolicitante").val()
                                            } 
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#retorno").html("<div class='row text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'><img src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/miniload.gif' alt='Carregando'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $( "#retorno" ).html( data ); 
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        function limpar(){
            carregar_form();
        };
    </script>
    <style>
        .titulo {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #0054bf; 
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.3);
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if IE]><?php imprimeMenuHeaderAugustaIE('faleAtendimento', 'Classif', @$_SESSION[ "bp" ])?><![endif]-->
    <!--[if ! IE]><!--><?php imprimeMenuHeaderAugusta('faleAtendimento', 'Classif', @$_SESSION[ "bp" ]) ?><!--<![endif]-->

    <section id="content">
        <section id="main"> 
            <div id="form_classificador"></div>
        </section>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
<?php 
    } else { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='".RAIZ."';</script>";
    }
?>
```

**-classificador_HelpCenter_ajax.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    include 'classificador_HelpCenter_sql.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

    $seccion = $_POST["seccion"];
    @$Atendimento = $_POST['Atendimento'];
    @$Solicitante = $_POST['Solicitante'];
    @$subSolicitante = $_POST['subSolicitante'];

    if($seccion == "carregarForm"){ carregarForm();}
    if($seccion == "carregarSubSolicitante"){ carregarSubSolicitante($Solicitante);}
    if($seccion == "guardar"){ guardar($Atendimento, $Solicitante, $subSolicitante);}
    if($seccion == "carregarAtendimento"){ carregarAtendimento($Atendimento);}

function carregarForm(){


    $Solicitantes = obtiene_filtros('Solicitante', null);

    $out = '<div class="panel panel-default col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="padding:0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" id="bodyForm">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">';
                        $out.='<fieldset>
                            <legend>Classificador Help Center</legend>';
                            if(true){ //NomeOperador
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filtro_NomeOperador" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Usuário</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_Nome" disabled value="'.$_SESSION['nomeGuerra'].'">
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){//Atendimento
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Atendimento">Atendimento</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Atendimento" onchange="carregarAtendimento($Atendimento);"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){//Solicitante
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Solicitante">Solicitante</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Solicitante" onchange="carregarSubSolicitante();">';
                                            foreach ($Solicitantes as $v){
                                                $out.='<option value="'.utf8_decode($v['valor']).'">'.utf8_decode($v['valor']).'</option>';
                                            }
                                        $out.='</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){ //subSolicitante
                                $out.='<div class="form-group" id="div_subSolicitante">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_SubSolicitante">Nome</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_SubSolicitante"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            $out.='</fieldset>';
                        if(true){ //botões
                            $out.='<fieldset style="margin-top: 15px;" id="retorno">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
                                    <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="limpar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-close"></i>&nbsp;Cancelar</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                                    <div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="guardar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Salvar</div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>';
                        }
                    $out.='</form>
                </div>
            </div>';

echo $out;
}
function carregarSubSolicitante($Solicitante){

    $filtro_duvida = obtiene_filtros('subSolicitante',utf8_decode($Solicitante));

    $out = '<label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_SubSolicitante">Nome</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_SubSolicitante">';
            foreach ($filtro_duvida as $v){
                $out .= "<option value='".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."'>".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."</option>";
            }
        $out.='</select>
        </div>
    </div>';
echo $out;
}



function carregarAtendimento($Atendimento){

        $filtro = obtiene_Atendimento($Atendimento);

        $out = '<label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Atendimento">Atendimento</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Atendimento">';
            foreach ($filtro as $v){
                $out .= "<option value='".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."'>".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."</option>";
            }
        $out.='</select>
        </div>
    </div>';
echo $out;
}
function guardar($Atendimento, $Solicitante, $subSolicitante){
        if(guardarResposta(utf8_decode($Atendimento),utf8_decode($Solicitante),utf8_decode($subSolicitante))){
            $out = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                Dados salvos com sucesso.
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" onclick="limpar()">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Novo
                </div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            $out = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                Erro ao Salvar! <br> Tente novamente em alguns segundos <br> caso o erro persista informe seu lider
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="limpar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Novo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="guardar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Salvar</div>
            </div>
            ';
        }

    echo $out;
}


?>
```

**-classificador_HelpCenter_sql.php**

```
<?php 
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    include '..\..\complemento\sql_login.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

        function obtiene_Atendimento($Atendimento){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        $sql= "SELECT T.Atendimento
            FROM classificadorHelpCenter_atendimento AS T";

        $resultado = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $arreglo =  utf8_encode( $fila[ "Atendimento" ] );
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $resultado );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return @$arreglo;

    }
    function obtiene_filtros ($filtro,$aux){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        if($filtro=='Solicitante'){
            $sql = "SELECT A.SOLICITANTE AS valor
                FROM classificadorHelpCenter_solicitante AS A
                GROUP BY A.SOLICITANTE ORDER BY A.SOLICITANTE";
        }
        if($filtro=='subSolicitante'){
            $sql = "SELECT A.SUBSOLICITANTE AS valor
            FROM classificadorHelpCenter_solicitante AS A
            WHERE A.SOLICITANTE = '".$aux."'
            GROUP BY A.SUBSOLICITANTE
            ORDER BY A.SUBSOLICITANTE";
        }

        $resultado = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $arreglo[] = array( 
                "valor"     => utf8_encode( $fila[ "valor" ] ),
            );
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $resultado );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return $arreglo;
    }   
    function guardarResposta($Atendimento, $Solicitante, $SubSolicitante){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        $sql="INSERT INTO fale_classificadorHelpCenter_registros (nome, bp, lider, Solicitante, Subsolicitante, data, Atendimento)
        VALUES( '".$_SESSION['nomeGuerra']."', '".$_SESSION['bp']."', '".$_SESSION['contrato_resumido']."', '".$Solicitante."', '".$SubSolicitante."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' ,'".$Atendimento."')";

        $arreglo = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return $arreglo;
    }


?>
```

Tudo que está relacionado a Atendimento, tentei usar a mesma configuração do campo Solicitante. O campo Atendimento aparece no formulário, porém quando clico, não trás o resultado da consulta sql que fiz.

Preciso fazer com que a lista seja exibida.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Cara.. olhando por cima deu pra ver comentários HTML dentro do JS.
`<script><!-- carregar form --></script>` não é JS válido. Talvez tenha a ver com teu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você deve observar o retorno da chamada a service classificador_HelpCenter_ajax 
no console do navegador / abra a aba NetWork  procure em Name => classificador_HelpCenter_ajax  e clique nele do lado direito tem Preview e Response, você clicando neles vc deve ver o que está retornando para a página html no caso você tem que ver se está retornando Atendimento. Espero ter ajudado.